# background-position у картинки

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Здравствуйте!

При клике на ссылку с классом `klik`, берется значение `background-position-y` у div-а с классом `img` (фоном div является картинка), все отлично работает, но когда я добавляю для класса `img` css свойство `transition: .5s;` при быстром клике на ссылку шаг `background-position-y` сбивается. Это все из-за анимации, видимо не успевает. Как можно это исправить?

JS:

```
$('.klik').on('click', function(){
   var klik = parseInt($('.img').css('background-position-y'),10);
   var sum = klik + 50;
   $('.img').css('background-position-y', sum);
   return false;
});
```

CSS:

```
.img{transition: .5s;}
```

Вот [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/5sqjx82f/5/).

Comment: Попробуйте использовать для этих целей .animate,  если вам нужно плавно сместить блок

Comment: @Alexander Goroshev К сожалению при `.animate` такая же проблема:(